# Move both sidebars more to their sides

Tags: css

this is the link to my website https://www.shockinpoop.com/. I want to move both the sidebars more to their sides of the page because as you can see, they each leave a considerable amount of space on their sides. Also after moving the sidebars, i want to make the content area wider. So can anybody tell me the css for this? Help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think your issue is specific to the theme (which, it appears, you got from ThemeFoundry). Can you get support from the theme documentation/authors?

Comment: Well, they don't exactly respond quickly. I have another query pending with them for 3 days now. Is there nothing I can do?

Comment: Perhaps you can describe what you have already tried? That would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Your Complete website has a max width of 1024]

So your main Container the part with the content area and sidebar goes to a max width of 1024px. if you increase it then the sidebars will stay the same width and the extra width goes to your content area.

Now how do you do this:
in you style.css on line 470 this part is defined and you can edit it there. but remember this could break your site if you go overboard with the widening.

further if you just want the container to widen and not the header, footer et al. then just add this css

```
.container {max-width:1170px!important;}
```

the `!important` will make sure this [style is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean).

You can also remove the `max-width:1024px;` bit and see the website as below.
[image: full width website]

Comment: Hi, thank you for you reply. I added this code to my style.css but nothing happened. I deleted cache and cleared history but still nothing.

Comment: was looking at your css files to see, and couldn't find your changes... also removing the max-width bit also make the entire site look nice and wider. will update my answer with a screenshot.